# What's wrong with this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

So I made a question which is basically the same question as one which it was voted up but at the same time with a relevant difference, but it keeps getting votes down. I see no reason why it is getting voted down. The question is,

[is there any free app to make a post with image to a Facebook group you arent admin of?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/108280/is-there-any-free-app-to-make-a-post-with-image-to-a-facebook-group-you-arent-ad)

which it is the same than [Is there a way to automatically post to a Facebook group?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/28481/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-post-to-a-facebook-group) but with the difference the later is meant to post to groups of Facebook you arent and admin of (the first question is answered for facebook groups you are an admin of) . What's wrong with this question? is it seen as duplicate? is it seen as a "software recommendation" because of its title, even though essentially it's the same kind of question than the first one?  does it have a bad title?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're asking for an app recommendation. Those are explicitly off-topic here. You might try [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com), but be sure to read their question guidance, as they have stringent question guidelines.

You may be able to get your question to be on-topic if you focus on the *problem* you're trying to solve, rather than finding the *solution* you've already decided you need.

As for the question you link to for reference, note that it's five years old. App recommendation questions were okay back then.

Comment: I changed the title to "is there any way to make an automatic post with image to a Facebook group you arent admin of?" but I'm afraid I'm going to get answers as paid app recommendations which it isnt the answer I'm looking for